# nth child css selector is not working properly with class names

Tags: html, css

The two div's are all green. What is happening? I just set it to blue using the child selector!

```css
div.stuff {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
}

div.stuff-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="stuff">123</div>
<div class="stuff">abc</div>
```

Comment: Try `div.stuff:nth-child(2)`

Comment: `.stuff-child(2)` is not at all valid CSS syntax. Why do you think that is valid?

Answer (score 1):

```
div.stuff:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

div.stuff {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
}

div.stuff:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
div.stuff:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="stuff">123</div>
    <div class="stuff">abc</div>
    <div class="stuff">xyz</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>

    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
    <div class="item">item 10</div>
    <div class="item">item 11</div>
    <div class="item">item 12</div>

  </div>
```

```
.item-wrap .item{ background-color: aqua; margin-bottom: 6px; height: 40px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; }
```

```
/* Select the 2nd list item */
.item-wrap .item:nth-child(2){ background-color: bisque;  }
```

OR

```
/* Select every 3rd list item starting with 2nd */
.item-wrap .item:nth-child(3n - 1){ background-color: bisque;  }
```

OR

```
/* Select every 2nd child item, as long as it has class "item" */
.item-wrap .item:nth-child(2n){ background-color: bisque;  }
```

OR

```
/* Select every other list item starting with 2nd */
.item-wrap .item:nth-child(even) { background-color: bisque; }
```

Answer (score 0):

no need for div before class declaration.
This should be enough:

```
.stuff {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
}

.stuff:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```